# Icon in top Corner using Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hi I am trying to add an icon in the top right corner of a span.

But I cannot figure it out.

Can anyone help?

```
<div class="tagset">
<span class="badge badge-grey">User <i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
<span class="badge badge-grey">Add Me <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
<span class="badge badge-grey">Loss Me <i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
</div>
```

looking for something like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boostrap-4 does have `.classes` for a situation like this. So You need  to write some  custom CSS.

Use `postion:relative` on `.badge` elements and  `postion:absolute` on icons.

```css
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px !important;
}

.fas {
  padding: .2rem .3rem;
  position: absolute;
  /* You may need to change top and right. They depend on padding/widht of .badge */
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tagset mt-5">
  <span class="badge bg-primary position-relative">User <i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
  <span class="badge bg-primary position-relative">Add Me <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
  <span class="badge bg-primary position-relative">Loss Me <i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
</div>
```

Read this [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) should you need more info.